# How to reduce render size?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, file-format, tilesize

i created an animation which is about 58 seconds, animation is mostly about rotating object 360 degrees 6 times and changing colour of one piece of the object 12 times. I wanted my animation to have transparent background to i can edit it freerely afterwards in premiere pro or after affects, so i used fmpeg codec with RGBA colour channel, quicktime encoding and engine im using is Evee. I set resolution to 3840x3840. So the biggest problem is that my render size is 55 GB. I would like to reduce it to at least 2 GB and would be amazing if was possible to even 500 MB. Can you guys help me?

Comment: first question: do you really need 3840 pixels? if you could use a lower resolution, this would lower the size a lot....

Comment: yea using 1920*1920 would be 1/4 (estimation) of those 55GB + you can change Output quality to something lower (if you didn't already used default value set to 'medium') but this can lower quality of your video a lot so you should test a shorter version with it first

Comment: I think there is other software out there to re-encode video files and I wouldn't actually leave it up to Blender to get the best possible result - I would rather go for the best quality you can get out of it and then use some dedicated software for video optimization. But that's off topic on this site and very localized for this specific case.

Comment: thank you so much guys